# How get user information with ASP.NET 4.5 from ADFS 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, adfs3.0

I'm trying get user information from ADFS 3.0 with Visual Studio 2013 (ASP.NET 4.5 application) but I can`t. I've completed the authentication but I don't have access to user information.

When I see the results of next instruction:

```
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims;
```

I get this:

```
[0] = {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn: Administrador@dreamworks.com}
[1] = {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport}
[2] = {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant: 2014-12-10T08:35:48.717Z}
```

This is all.

Comment: Are you using the OAuth2 end points to authenticate the user

Comment: In the first line of the result, there you find the "user principal name". Wouldn't that be what you are looking for?